# Is there a principle of comparison for mild-solutions?

Tags: reference-request, parabolic-pde

We consider the equations of the form
\begin{equation}\label{Eq.un}
    \left\{ 
    \begin{array}{rll}
        u_t -  \Delta u &=  |\cdot|^{\gamma}u^{p}& \mbox{ in } \mathbb{R}^n \times (0,T), \\    
        {u}(0) &=  {u}_{0}& \mbox{ in } \mathbb{R}^n, \\
    \end{array}
    \right.
\end{equation}

where $p>1$ and $-2<\gamma<0.$

Any function $u$ satisfying  $u(0) = u_0$ and
\begin{equation}\label{mild-sol}
    u(t) = S(t)u_0 + \int_{0}^{t} S(t-s)|\cdot|^{\gamma}|\nabla u(s)|^p ds
\end{equation}

is called a mild solution.

Wang in [ON THE CAUCHYPROBLEMFOR REACTION-DIFFUSIONEQUATIONS](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1993-337-02/S0002-9947-1993-1153016-5/S0002-9947-1993-1153016-5.pdf) says that when $\gamma<0$ it is generally impossible to obtain a classical solution for the problem. the author himself makes a version of the comparison principle for mild upper and lower solutions. I would like to know if there are more general principles of comparison in the literature for mild solutions, including for example, for subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$, or other non-linear terms. I appreciate any comments.

remark: on the book Superlinear Parabolic Problems_ Blow-up, Global Existence and Steady States of Souplet, has numerous principles of comparison, but they are for classical solutions.